# Implementing Recycle Scroller In Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a huge amount of data from an API and when I try to show it at one time, it is lagging.
I decided to use Recycle scroller, but I couldn't implement it. Here is my data;

```
async created() {
    this.loaded = false;

    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        'SOME_API'
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      data.forEach(element => {
        // console.log(element.symbol, element.lastPrice);
        this.chartData.symbols = [...this.chartData.symbols, element.symbol];
        // We take the volume
        this.chartData.price = [...this.chartData.price, +element.lastPrice];
      });

      // console.log(this.chartData.symbols);
      this.loaded = true;
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  },
```

My arrays to iterate it as a lists

```
computed: {
    pairs() {
      return this.chartData.symbols.map((symbol, i) => {
        return {
          symbol: symbol,
          price: this.chartData.price[i],
        };
      });
    },
  },
```

My data:

```
data: () => ({
    dialog: false,
    search: '',
    btnText: 'Add Stock',
    numberValue: 1,
    chartData: {
      symbols: [],
      price: [],
    },
  }),
```

The main code I want to change and implement the recycle scroller, `v-for` is here also I implement vue2filters. I used vuetify for designing. How can I implement to scroll into below codes?

```
  <v-row>
              <v-list-item
                v-for="pair in filterBy(pairs, search)"
                :key="pair.symbol"
              >
                <v-list-item-content>
                  <!-- <RecycleScroller
                    class="scroller"
                    :items="pair"
                    :item-size="32"
                    key-field="id"
                    v-slot="{pair}"
                  > -->
                  <v-list-item-title
                    >{{ pair.symbol }} - {{ pair.price }}</v-list-item-title
                  >
                  <!-- </RecycleScroller> -->
                </v-list-item-content>
                <v-text-field
                  outlined
                  v-model="numberValue"
                  hide-details
                  single-line
                  type="number"
                  class="shrink mr-2"
                  width="50px"
                  height="50px"
                />
                <v-btn class="btn" dark md color="success"> Add </v-btn>
              </v-list-item>
            </v-row>
```